# How to return a list of data from my database?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return the users details for a profile but not too sure how. This is what I have so far but not sure if it's even close.

```
public static async Task<List<UserProf>> ProfileSetUp(string userName, string firstName, string lastName, string profession, string county, string description)
    {
        CurrentPlatform.Init();
        List<UserProf> ls = await Client.GetTable<UserProf>().ToListAsync();
        UserProf u = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == userName);
        UserProf f = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Firstname == firstName);
        UserProf l = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Lastname == lastName );
        UserProf p = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Profession == profession);
        UserProf c = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.County == county);
        UserProf d = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Description == description);

        List<string> profileList = new List<string>
        {
            userName,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            profession,
            county,
            description
        };
        return profileList;
    }
```

It's giving me an error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collection.Generic.List<string>` to `System.Collection.Generic.List<AppName.UserProf>`"

Tried a few solutions to fix but it fixs one error and gives another:

> "the return type of an async method must be void Task or Task"

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Why are you trying to return a `List<string>` as a `List<UserProf>`? Looks like you want to return a `new List<UserProf> { u, f, l, p, c, d }`...

Comment: Your code seems to just return the passed in parameters. Don't you want to do something with the 6 `UserProf` objects?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes I'm trying to return those values but have no idea how, I pulled this together from online tutorials

Comment: @crashmstr yes, i want to display the 6 objects in a form of a profile to the user

Comment: @Jon that doesn't make any sense at all. You pass all the data you need to build the list, look for the first users that match certain criteria and then you want to return their values that you just checked with `==`? You would be returning the exact same data you pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want is just a single user based on username and then you can compare that in the calling code to see if the properties are the same or not.

```
public static Task<UserProf> ProfileSetUp(string userName)
{
    CurrentPlatform.Init();
    return Client.GetTable<UserProf>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == userName);
}
```

---

I think you are trying to filter the database and return a list of matches based on the input.

```
public static async Task<List<UserProf>> ProfileSetUp(string userName, string firstName, string lastName, string profession, string county, string description)
{
    CurrentPlatform.Init();
    return await Client.GetTable<UserProf>()
        .Where(x => x.Username == userName
                && x.Firstname == firstName
                && x.Lastname == lastName
                && x.Profession == profession
                && x.County == county
                && x.Description == description)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

If you want to match where any of the conditions is met then replace all `&&` with `||` for OR.

---

There is also no need for `async/await` as you do not need to wait for the results inside the method. Here is the second variation without that and using OR for any match.

```
public static Task<List<UserProf>> ProfileSetUp(string userName, string firstName, string lastName, string profession, string county, string description)
{
    CurrentPlatform.Init();
    return Client.GetTable<UserProf>()
        .Where(x => x.Username == userName
                || x.Firstname == firstName
                || x.Lastname == lastName
                || x.Profession == profession
                || x.County == county
                || x.Description == description)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for, so I'll be able to output the likes of "userName" or "firstName" to the user by calling that name?

Comment: @Jon - not sure what you want to output but yes, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: When the user created their profile these details saved to the database, I'm trying to output the details they gave in the form of a profile, sorry if i'm just repeating myself, just trying to clear it up

Comment: @Jon - if you want a single user then you need `First` or `Single`. It would be better to retrieve the user by username or userid.

Comment: @Jon - see my update at the top, I think you just want this.

Comment: I'm hoping to call all the users details, not just the username

Comment: @Jon - correct, this will return the entire user object for the one user based on username.

Comment: Well then that should work perfectly, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: How do i get the __SingleOrDefaultAsync__ working? I keep getting the error __"'IMobileServiceTable<UserProf>' does not contain a definition for SingleOrDefaultAsync__" ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem with __"singleordefault"__ is __"using System.Linq"__ but linq is staying blank, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are:

1. You aren't returning the right type.  You didn't give the full error message (you edited it as I wrote this).  It's saying a `List<string>` doesn't implicitly convert to a `List<UserProf>`.
2. You aren't using your variables.   You're populating a return value based on the parameters you passed to the method, not the return values of your lambda expressions.

This should fix your problem:

```
        List<UserProf> profileList = new List<UserProf>
        {
            u,
            f,
            l,
            p,
            c,
            d
        };
        return profileList;
```

I don't think you'll get what you want, though.  I think what you really want is to return one user profile with each of these string values, so you may need to change the function signature to return one single `UserProf`, create the object in your function, then return the object.  You can do that in one lambda:

```
 UserProf u = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => 
      x.Username == username 
      && x.Firstname == firstname
      && x.Lastname == lastname 
      && x.Profession == profession 
      && x.County == county 
      && x.Description == description);
```

Also, use proper naming conventions.  Compound words like "username" for variables should be "userName" and properties like "x.Firstname" should be "x.FirstName" in the object definition. VS 2017 will call that out as a warning if you don't camel or pascal case your compound words.

Comment: I'm testing this atm but not too sure how to call the likes of "username" or "firstname" below, I'm just trying a simple toast call. Any idea how I call them?